# how to get validated value of angular FormGroup having property values of non undefined type?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, typeguards

I have a `FormGroup`:

```
data = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl<string>('', { validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true }),
    description: new FormControl<string>('', { validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true })
  });
```

and for `const offer: OfferInput = this.data.value;` I'm getting below error which absolutely makes sense as property values can be undefined eg for disabled form (well default empty string may not be fortunate here but let's leave it for now).

```
  Types of property 'description' are incompatible.
   Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I wonder if there is any existing method or common reasonable construct which gives access to a validated value where type of properties are not undefined thanks to `Validators.required`. Similarly `nonNullable: true` already helps making type of properties to not be null.

I can do some forced casting after checking `data.valid`, just wondering about any more TS-wise way.

Comment: Not quite following the question…`this.data.getRawValue()` will give the value including disabled controls. Also recommend putting the model on the form group `FormGroup<IFormModel>({…`

Comment: just checked and indeed `getRawValue()` gives me an object with non undefined properties. My guess by the name was that `getRawValue()` is no really processed in any way and so type will be same as `this.data.value` - I did'n even bother to check. I'd be happy to approve this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

[FormGroup - getRawValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)

> The aggregate value of the `FormGroup`, including any disabled controls.

Usage `this.formGroup.getRawValue()`.

As stated in question `this.formGroup.value` is a Partial type due to potentially disabled controls.

Note `Validators.minLenth` is available and can be used with other validators.

Comment: There’s [zod](https://zod.dev/) (8kB minified+zipped) if you want mix validation and type inference, though this is more typically used on the backend. e.g. tRPC to infer types from the backend to use in front end